# SVM for one class and one feature with Matlab fitcsvm gives overfitted results

Tags: matlab, svm

I am trying to use SVM in the simplest possible way, for classifying a target category (class 1) with a range of values greater than some, and lower than other non-targets (class 0). However, the model I fit is too complex, and instead of giving me two support vectors, results in a bad separation between categories. I assume the model has too many dimensions and is therefore heavily overfitted. I tried changing 'KernelScale' but it is not it. Do you know how I can force the model to be simpler?

```
n0 = normrnd(0,1,300,1);
n1 = normrnd(1,1,300,1);
n2 = normrnd(2,1,300,1);

val = [n0;n1;n2];
lbl = [zeros(300,1);ones(300,1);zeros(300,1)];

d = fitcsvm(val, cellstr(str(lbl))','KernelScale', 'auto','KernelFunction','gaussian');
pred = ismember(d.predict(val),'1');
figure;
plot([1:300,601:900],val([1:300,601:900]),'.b')
hold on;
plot(301:600,val(301:600),'.r')
plot(find(pred),val(pred),'og')
legend('class 0','class 1','predicted class 1','location','southeast')
```

[image]